# Cannot read property 'value' of null | angular-recaptcha

Tags: angularjs, recaptcha

In my SPA I am using angular-recaptcha. I have a reCaptcha form in two separate places. If I complete any of the reCaptchas I cannot complete the other or the same one again until I clear my cache.

**Error:**

> Cannot read property 'value' of null

I found some resources online like:
https://gedgei.wordpress.com/2015/08/07/using-recaptcha-in-single-page-applications/

I followed that guide to the best of my ability and the error persists.

**html:**

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" vc-recaptcha key="publicKey" on-create=getRecaptchaId(widgetId)">
```

**controller:**

```
  var newWidgetId;

  $scope.getWidgetId = function(widgetId) {
    newWidgetId = widgetId;
    return;
  };

  var reCaptcha = vcRecaptchaService.getResponse(newWidgetId)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `on-create` event handler `getRecaptchaId(widgetId)` is not bounded to the scope of your controller.

On your controller, change:

```
var getWidgetId = function(widgetId) {
    newWidgetId = widgetId;
    return;
};
```

To:

```
$scope.getRecaptchaId = function(widgetId) {
    newWidgetId = widgetId;
    return;
};
```

Comment: look at the name in the view and in the controller `getRecaptchaId` != `getWidgetId`